# Not a valid win32 application while launching the installer

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, installation, nsis

I have created a c# application using visual studio 2012 and uses a 4.5 framework.I created an Installer using **NSIS(HM-NIS-EDIT Wizard)**.The installer works fine on windows 7 32 and 64 bit.But when I tried running the installer on windows Xp, it gave me an **error saying not a valid win32 application**.I want that it should work on windows XP as well.

I wanted to know what the possible reason could be.

1)Should I change the framework to 3.0 or 3.5?

2)Or do i have to change the code in NSIS.

Please suggest

Link of my installer https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrxp4fswnqydu9t/Usm.exe

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET 4.5 is not supported on Windows XP. There's no way to go around this. .NET 4.0 is the last version that supported Windows XP SP3. You can add many 4.5 features using NuGet packages like [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) for `async/await` support and [Microsoft.Net.Http](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) for HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks Panagiotic I'll try that.But would changing the framework to 4.0 solve the issue..?

Comment: I can't tell you that without the exact error message or looking at the installer's log. You may have tried to run a 64-bit installer on a 32-bit machine, in which case installation didn't even start. It's certain though that the 4.5 program won't run on Windows XP.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrxp4fswnqydu9t/Usm.exe this is the link of my installer.I would be grateful if you would test it on your system.I am new to .net and still learning

the error message is not a valid win32 application

Comment: And I have packaged both 32 and 64bit installer into one package which will detect the OS that you're using and based on that copy the files to either ProgramFiles(32) or 64 folder

Answer (score 0):

I think your installer is not created with NSIS but with Advanced Installer. I tried to run it on Win7 Pro 64bit and the result is "The system could not find the file specified.".

Comment: Sorry @Slappy,I was also experimenting with Advanced Installer.I added a .exe file to the main installation package using Advanced Installer but when I run it on a clients computer it gives an error saying  "The system could not find the file specified.".Will you help me fix this?

The link to nsis installer is

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrxp4fswnqydu9t/Usm.exe)